# Time::ParseDate install fail

Tags: windows, perl, module, cpan

I'm trying to install a module to manipulate times in the format HHMMSS--just to find basic time differences and such. Time::ParseDate looks like a perfect candidate, but I'm having some trouble installing it.

I'm on perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread.

The command:

```
cpan Time::ParseDate
```

returns

```
Set up gcc environment - 4.4.7 20111023 (prerelease) [svn/rev.180339 - mingw-w64/oz]
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Time::ParseDate
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Cannot copy 'lib/Time/JulianDay.pm' to 'blib\lib\Time\JulianDay.pm': No such     file or directory
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'pm_to_blib'
  MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz
  C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Could someone explain exactly what's going awry? It looks like I'm missing lib/Time/JulianDay.pm, but why? Do I have to update my version of Perl or my version of Cpan?

I deleted the Autorun registry key, and then retried the install. I got:

```
CPAN: Term::ANSIColor loaded ok (v4.02)
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.34)
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 05 Nov 2013 20:53:02 GMT
 Running install for module 'Time::ParseDate'
 Running make for M/MU/MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz
 CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.84)
   CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.06)
 Checksum for C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MU\MUIR\modules\Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz ok
 CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.90)
 Time-ParseDate-2013.0920/
 etc...
Time-ParseDate-2013.0920/t/datetime.t
 CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
 CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4404)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.120921)
 CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.80)

 CPAN.pm: Building M/MU/MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - 4.4.7 20111023 (prerelease) [svn/rev.180339 - mingw-w64/oz]
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Time::ParseDate
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/Time/JulianDay.pm blib\lib\Time\JulianDay.pm
cp lib/Time/CTime.pm blib\lib\Time\CTime.pm
cp lib/Time/ParseDate.pm blib\lib\Time\ParseDate.pm
cp lib/Time/DaysInMonth.pm blib\lib\Time\DaysInMonth.pm
cp lib/Time/Timezone.pm blib\lib\Time\Timezone.pm
  MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz
  C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.39)
Running make test
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',    'blib\arch')" t/*
t/datetime.t .. ok
t/metdate.t ... skipped: It seems localtime() does not honor $ENV{TZ} when set in the  test script.
t/order1.t .... 1/?
#   Failed test 'Europe/Moscow, DST permanent 2009'
#   at t/order1.t line 34.
#          got: '1257030000'
#     expected: '1257022800'

#   Failed test 'Europe/Moscow, DST permanent 2013'
#   at t/order1.t line 35.
#          got: '1369868400'
#     expected: '1369857600'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 5.
t/order1.t .... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/5 subtests
t/order2.t .... 1/?
#   Failed test 'Europe/Moscow, DST permanent 2013'
#   at t/order2.t line 34.
#          got: '1369868400'
#     expected: '1369857600'

#   Failed test 'Europe/Moscow, DST permanent 2009'
#   at t/order2.t line 35.
#          got: '1257030000'
#     expected: '1257022800'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 5.
t/order2.t .... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/5 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/order1.t  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 5 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  3-4
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/order2.t  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 5 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  3-4
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=4, Tests=331,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.16 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/4 test programs. 4/331 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz
  C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MUIR/modules/Time-ParseDate-2013.0920.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Comment: Can you install any other module successfully ?

Comment: When I try to install `ExUtils::MakeMaker` I get `CPAN: 
dmake.exe:  makefile:  line 527:  Warning: -- Macro BOOTSTRAP' redefined after use
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Cannot copy 'lib/ExtUtils/MM_OS2.pm' to 'blib\lib\ExtUtils\MM_OS2.pm': No such file or directory
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'pm_to_blib'
  BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.82.tar.gz
  C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK` etc...

Comment: Even when I try to upgrade cpan I get the same error.

Comment: Did you mess with HKEY->Software->Microsoft->Command processor->autorun

Comment: Can you try `cpan` and then `look Time::ParseDate` and take a look in the directory, e.g. to check whether files are missing here? Another idea: you have changed your PATH.

Comment: @SlavenRezic the path has about 4 different versions of perl. I could post the path value here if that would be helpful

Comment: @dusan.bajic: actually, yes. I changed it so that I wouldn't have to change directories every time I opened the command prompt.

Comment: Try to remove the other perls from `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time-ParseDate's test suite simply does not pass on Windows systems. See http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Time-ParseDate or http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Time-ParseDate;maxver=1 . I tried it myself with both Strawberry Perl and ActivePerl, and the test suite failed with both perls (the tests need to fiddle with the TZ environment variable, but this works differently on Windows systems than on Unix/Linux systems, see also the bug report https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=90367).

You can try to install the module untested by forcing the install or skipping the tests. In the CPAN shell:

```
force install Date::JulianDay
```

or

```
notest install Date::JulianDay
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your Autorun setting in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" is navigating child processes during installation away from current path, resulting in files being created in wrong place.

Comment: Is the default path `C:\Windows\System32 `?

Comment: Or should I just delete autorun?

Comment: Well, it doesn't hurt to try (you can export reg key before deleting if you think you might need it later).

Comment: I did so and then tried again. I got the errors above (at least they're new errors!).

Comment: When it says ` C:\Dwimperl\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK`, does that indicate that it is using that perl to create the module? Why would it do so when there are other (more updated) perls in the `path`?

Comment: How do I direct it to a different Perl?